# Offline Data Sync in Azure with MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure, azure-mobile-services

It appears from [Announcing general availability of App Service Mobile Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-general-availability-of-app-service-mobile-apps/) that Offline Data Sync is possible with a backend that uses MongoDB for data storage in Azure.

I have tried to implement this in various ways with both the old and the new mobile services/app variants.

Lets ignore my epic fail-story with the old (Mobile Service?) way and focus on the new way, with a App Service backend that is implemented in C#.

I set it up with SQL Server since MongoDB is not in the dropdown list. After setting it up in the Azure control panel i download the quick start TodoItems application and it works.

I use the todoitems-client to test the backend.

I enable Offline sync in the client and it works.

Then i try to change the type of the DataObject TodoItem int the backend to DocumentData from EntityData in order to replace SQL-server with MongoDB.

This is where i find out that the Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Backend.Mongo package is not available like it was when i tried the old version of offline sync.

What i would like to know is:

o Has anyone got this setup to work?
o If so, how?

Thanks,
Mattias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Mongo database support is not built-in to the Azure Mobile Apps server SDK. Sync is supported, but it requires that you build a custom Domain Manager for Mongo DB.

Comment: is it the same for DocumentDB? is it  built-in for Azure mobile apps SDK?

Answer (score 1):

You can sync a mobile database with MongoDB via SiaqodbCloud which is open source and can be hosted in Azure: https://github.com/Dotissi/SiaqodbCloud-Service